# Control what services are published by Avahi?

Tags: ios, printing, samba, cups, avahi

I've configured a print server on Raspbian (Jessie) using CUPS, SAMBA and Avahi to publish a USB printer to iOS devices. It works fine except when it comes time to actually print, the printer isn't found. (even after selecting the printer in the Printer Options dialog in iOS.)

I believe this is either related to 1) multiple services with the same name being published by Avahi 2) some kind of timeout between printer selection and printing or 3) the address of the printer changing somehow at each access.

In order to explore the first problem, I'd like to try to disable all but the _ipp._tcp. service for the printer. (simply by sharing a printer in CUPS, I get a Printer@Server over _ipp._tcp., _ipps._tcp. and _printer._tcp.)

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer, since you do not provide *ANY* details about *how* exactly your setup of the different components (CUPS, Samba, Avahi) is and how exactly you proceeded to publish the print queues. However, I can tell you that much already: if you disable its *`_ipps._tcp.`* and *`_printer._tcp.`* Bonjour/Avahi service announcements, iOS devices will no longer list the respective print queue.

Comment: You may want to [browse *my other Bonjour/Avahi-related answers*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A359307+Bonjour) for some hints about your problem.

Comment: I installed CUPS and configured a shared USB printer. I installed SAMBA and enabled printer sharing. I installed Avahi. That's as specific as I can be because that's all that was necessary to get it working. Thanks for the links to the other answers. I'll take a look.

Comment: If you got it *all* working, your questions make no sense.... If your printing doesn't work, because your printer isn't found, *my* questions make all sense.

Comment: I didn't get it "all" working and didn't say I did. And you didn't ask any questions. Are you responding to a different comment than you intended? It's been 16 months since I asked this question.